# Dimension of V and W when the linear map is injective but not surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, and that $\phi : V \to W$ is a linear map that is injective but not surjective. What can you say about the dimensions of $V$ and $W$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Rank-Nullity Theorem,
$$ \dim V = \dim \ker \varphi + \dim \operatorname{im} \varphi = \dim \operatorname{im} \varphi < \dim W
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then $\{\phi(e_1),\ldots,\phi(e_n)\}$ is linear independent in $W$ (easy to show). Thus, $\dim W\ge n = \dim V$.